# compare value in every row of other pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a simple pandas dataframe which has a range column.

```
map_dict =    { 'range' : [50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 40000, 80000, 120000], 
               'sample' : [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000] }

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(map_dict)
```

I have a value lets say x now I want to compare x at every row in column range e.g. if x> 200 & x< 500 then sum x with the matching value in the column sample.

And another example, if x = 4000, because in this case x> 2000 & x< 5000 in the range column. so matching value in column sample will be 2000, so I will sum with 2000

```
output:6000
```

How can I compare a value in other data frame and get the matching value in the next column?

Comment: Can you please add an example of desired output?

Comment: What is output if x=2000 ?

Comment: @jezrael output 4000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need subtract values, compare by greater like `0` and get first matched value of `sample` column:

```
x = 4000

y = next(iter(df.loc[df['range'].sub(x) > 0, 'sample']))
#alternative for first matched value
#y = df.loc[ y > 0, 'sample'].to_numpy()[0]
print (y)
2000

print (x + y)
6000
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, little explanation around sub(x) > 0

Comment: @ManuSharma - First column is subtracted by `x` - `df['range'].sub(x)`, what is same like `df['range'] - x`, so get negative values for values lower like threshold, so filter out these values compared by `>0` and then get first matched value from `df.loc[df['range'].sub(x) > 0, 'sample']` - next and iter is used for get first value from filtered Series